# How should I repair this crack in the top of my tub's panel kit wall?

Tags: bathroom, shower, bathtub

I have a bath tub with "panel kit" above it that covers the 3 walls.
[image]

I noticed tonight that there's a crack on the top edge of the panel kit, near a seam.
[image]

My **question** is how can the crack be repaired?

Comment: that looks like a seam, not a crack

Comment: Is the crack just hard to see in the picture?  I only see the seam.

Comment: It looks like a seam that has started to separate, though maybe there is a crack at the back, to the left of the large vertical gap. You say you just noticed it, but has the vertical gap always been there or did this just open in the last day or so?

Comment: @FreeMan - The vertical seam is by design. What I'm not sure about is the crack that I circled in red.

Comment: I figured the seam was by design. Is the horizontal part that you've circled actually broken, or is it 2 parts that are starting to come apart? If it's a 1-piece surround that's actually cracking/breaking, then you _might_ get away with using epoxy to fix it, but I wouldn't count on it being watertight. You don't know how far down into the seam it's broken. If it's a 3-piece kit where the seams are simply separating, well, again epoxy, but again, who knows if the epoxy is getting all the way down the wall to where the panels are no longer separated.